# Usage of checked? in Capybara

Tags: checkbox, capybara

How can I use the instance method `checked?` in Capybara's `Class: Capybara::Node::Element` ?
I did not get any proper documentation on its usage!
we can use check and uncheck as below:

```
page.check('some_text')
page.uncheck('some_text')
```

but `page.checked?('some_text')` throws error. I want use checked? method itself to verify if a checkbox is set. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `checked?` method is available to the Capybara::Node::Element. `page` is a Capybara::Session object, which is why you get an undefined method error.

To use `checked?`, you need to get the checkbox element by using `find`, `find_field`, etc.

I assume the HTML of the page is something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="box" type="checkbox">
    <label for="box">some_text</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can get the checkbox, as a Capybara::Node::Element, by using:

```
page.find_field('some_text')
```

The `checked?` method can be used on the object returned by finder:

```
page.check('some_text')
p page.find_field('some_text').checked?
#=> true

page.uncheck('some_text')
p page.find_field('some_text').checked?
#=> false
```

Comment: Perfect!! using find_field and label text I was able to get whether checkbox is checked or not :)